# SSD based cache for Virtual machines

Tags: kernel, ssd, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, io

I have to complete an academic project on kvm+ssd. Topic is SSD based cache for Virtual machines.

I think when guest operating system issues read call, it will goes through KVM and then to host OS. I want to check whether the requested block is present in ssd cache or not when control comes to KVM. If it is present return the block from cache. Otherwise read from HDD, save to cache and return. There will be some mapping tables to provide isolation.

1. Suppose guest is trying access a block number x in virtual hard disk. So what will be the block number when KVM tries access the same? If block number is different where the conversion takes place ?
2. To implement this system, where should make modifications so that i can check it is cached or not ?

Comment: what's your guest and host OS ?

Comment: Host os is ubuntu 16.04 with linux 4.7.6.    Guest may be anything. i want to make guest unknown about caching.